# How do I add window stools to my new windows?

Tags: windows, trim

I installed new Jeld-Wen windows and saved the old stools.  I'm trying to figure out how they should be attached but these windows don't seem to be designed to take a stool -- they are flush with the drywall all around.  Referring to the picture, I can butt the stools up to the window wood and have them "floating", supported by trim piece underneath, but that would leave them susceptible to being pulled away from the wall it seems.  If I were to lay them on top of the window's existing wood, then the finger catch to lift the window would be blocked.  Is there a way to add a stool here besides having it float, or are these just designed to have no stool?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Family Handyman](http://www.familyhandyman.com/) has an article on [How to Install Craftsman Trim](http://www.familyhandyman.com/carpentry/trim-carpentry/how-to-install-craftsman-trim/view-all), which says to simply glue and nail the stool to the jamb using 2 1/2" finish nails.

Once you have the stool cut to length, add a bit of wood glue to the length that will sit against the window frame. Position the stool where you want it, and drill pilot holes through the stool and into the jamb using a 5/64 drill bit (using a clamp to hold the stool in place can be useful). Next, fit 8d finish nails through the stool and into the jamb. Install the apron tight up against the bottom of the stool, making sure to nail into the framing when attaching it.

You could install a more substantial apron, and additionally nail through the stool and into the apron. This will add a bit more support for the stool (especially if the apron is attached to the framing), but may or may not fit aesthetically with the rest of the trim.

Obviously with this method you'll not be able to do chin-ups from the stool. But once the nail holes are filled and the piece is finished, it should look nice for years to come.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could "float" them level with the existing frame, but screw in from the window side (through the face away from the room, into the part you call a stool that I'd call a sill) which would firmly attach the stool to the windowframe so it could not pull away from the wall.

They are probably designed not to have one, yes - "picture-framing" windows is one more place to cut costs, and cats and plants don't have effective lobbying groups to prevent it.